# Can i output a provider from a module in terraform?

Tags: terraform

I want to output a postgreql provider from a module in terraform then use it to further configure the database.

Current use case is a module creating a postgres rds instance and i want to return a "postgresql provider" to continue setting up the roles and databases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you cannot do that. You need to return the login values from the module so you can setup a provider outside the module using those values.

I would just edit the module and do what you need inside the module so you don't have to output those things.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing that, switch the principle and inject a Provider.

E.g. in your module you have

```
provider "azurerm" {
  version = "~> 1.16"
}
```

Now in the actual Environment I would switch to aliased Providers like

```
provider "azurerm" {
  version = "~> 1.16"
  alias   = "goldenrule"
}
```

Then you can inject it into the module like this

```
module "something-great" {
  source = "./great/thang/"
  providers = {
    azurerm  = "azurerm.goldenrule"
  }
}
```

Comment: and then inside the module, you reference that azurerm provider how? I'm getting errors when I try the obvious: provider = "azurerm"